# Help needed! What is wrong with my code?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

Error Message:

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \markboth  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \markright  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

) (./hello.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
Chapter 1.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--47


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--47


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 39--47

[1]
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.48     \section[Section One]{Section First}
```

My Whole Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1cm, outer=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext, graphicx, wrapfig, enumitem, fancyhdr, extramarks, amsmath, tikz, fontawesome, lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Ubuntu}
    \setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}
    \newfontfamily{\FAS}{Font Awesome 5 Free Solid}
    \newfontfamily{\FAR}{Font Awesome 5 Free Regular}
    \newfontfamily{\FAB}{Font Awesome 5 Brands Regular}

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \makeatletter
        \newcommand{\globalcolor}[1]{%
            \color{#1}\global\let\default@color\current@color
        }
    \makeatother
    \AtBeginDocument{\globalcolor{white}}

\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
    \backgroundsetup{
        scale=1,color=black,opacity=0.10,angle=0,contents={
            \includegraphics[height=15cm]{logo.png}
        }
    }

\usepackage{index}
    \makeindex

\begin{document}

    \BgThispage
    \pagecolor{darkgray}

    \chapter[Chapter OnE]{Chapter FiRsT}
    This is some text in the regular font.\\\\
    {\texttt{This is Typed in Ubuntu Mono.}}\\\\
    {\FAS{\symbol{"F0E0}}}\\
    {\FAS{\symbol{"F3C5}}}\\
    {\FAS{\symbol{"F095}}}\\
    {\FAS{\symbol{"F57D}}}\\\\
    \blindmathtrue
    \Blindtext[5]

    \section[Section One]{Section First}
    \Blindtext[6]

    \section[Section TwO]{Section SeCoNd}
    \Blindtext[6]

    \chapter[Chapter TwO]{Chapter SeCoNd}
    \Blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: the underfull box warnings are from the mis-placed `\\ `

Comment: misplaced \\ ? Where should I place them?

Comment: You should almost never need them in normal text and certainly never at the end of a paragraph or immediately after `\\ `  so just have `\\ ` not `\\\\ ` and don't have `\\ ` after the last item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `index` is not compatible with `extramarks`, because the latter requires commands that conflict with what the former wants to do.

There are better ways for supporting several indices and I can't recommend `index`, that hasn't been maintained for fifteen years and still advertises being version 4.2beta and does several redefinitions of important commands making it incompatible with other packages.

Please, note that `\\` is not the way to end paragraphs, which is done by leaving a blank line.

Also `\newfontface` should be the choice instead of `\newfontfamily` for fonts that have no variants:

```
\newfontface{\fasfont}{Font Awesome 5 Free Solid}
\NewDocumentCommand{\FAS}{m}{{\normalfont\fasfont\symbol{#1}}}
```

and `\FAS{"F0E0}` will be more robust and simpler.

Comment: Which package would you recommend instead of "index"

Comment: @YourPalNurav I (with C. Beccari) wrote `imakeidx`.

Comment: Well this proves internet is indeed a small little place. I had never imagined some developer would answer my question. Will try imakeidx next.